# The effects of frequency resolution in FFT on the frequency spectrum

Tags: dsp, frequency-measurement, fft

This is a section for the parameter study of my thesis (basically: why and how I did what I did in the experiments). Currently, I have to choose the fit bandwidth and FFT lines combination for the experiment (for the parameter study, it is just giving an impulse for the generator, or hitting the metal specimen with a hammer). Investigations (actual measurement) say that with frequency resolution under 0.1 Hz, the spectrum obtained would be very squishy. For example, right below is 12800 FFT lines (or 12800 FFT bins) with different bandwidths (0.5, 1, 2, 5, 10 and 20 kHz) and different frequency resolutions (39.1, 78.1, 156.3, 390.6, 781.3 and 1562.5 mHz respectively)

[image]

The spectrum with 39.1 and 78.1 mHz frequency resolution (blue and orange) are very "squishy"...

**Question 1**: Why do we have such squishy spectrum?

For reference: this is non-squishy spectrum

[image]

**Question 2**: At low-frequency range (<50 Hz), smaller FFT bin shows peak better (more data point on the same range of frequency, thus easier to spot the peaks). But why at high-frequency, smaller FFT bins lead to lower peaks (at 300 and 330 Hz)?

**Question 3**: Is there a "critical point" for frequency resolution? Or the trade-off between frequency resolution vs spectral/time resolution? If yes, is there any source you can point towards for me, or is this more like a rule of thumb?

Thank you for your support

Comment: you may ask this on https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ which is specific to these studies.

Comment: All resolutions are giving you correct answers, but they're giving you those answers to the different questions you are asking the data. So the question is, what question do you want to ask the data? Generally the peaks are interesting, the noise less so. Many people 'video average' adjacent bins together to suppress noise variance (is this what you mean by 'squishy'?) while maintaining other features. Many power average together the spectra of many runs. As you are writing a thesis, you ought to have a long think about precisely what the question you *ought* to be asking your data.

Comment: @Neil_UK Thanks for your comment. For the record, the above spectrum is averaged already (over 9 times of running, or take 9 measurements and average them out - this is done in a different section). For the thesis, I want to know, "at this peak (of this frequency), what is the transfer function value?" 
(well, this is a part of another question, but the whole thesis would be boiled down to that question)

Comment: How exactly is the averaging done ? can you provide the steps and the formulae ?

Comment: @AJN I use a computer (come with the whole measurement equipment package), so the program automatically finishes the averaging for me. Though for the record, I use complex-number based averaging over 9 samples.

Comment: By averaging 9 samples, do you mean **1)** 9 separate sensors mounted on the test subject averaged or **2)** experiment repeated 9 times or **3)** 9 consecutive samples averaged (thereby reducing the sample rate by 9 times or **4)** running average of 9 samples ? If the program that came with the computer is a black box, it will be difficult to interpret its results.

Comment: The last one, i.e.: running 9 samples and take their averages